# Neuroph cannot train set

Tags: java, neural-network

I've been trying so hard to train a network but I cannot do it. Neuroph Studio doesn't help at all, it always return null when training.
Then I tried this code in a Java app :

```
// create new perceptron network
NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new Perceptron(2, 1);

// create training set
DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(2, 1);

// add training data to training set (logical OR function)
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 0}, new double[]{0.5d}));
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 1}, new double[]{1}));
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 0}, new double[]{1}));
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 1}, new double[]{1}));

// learn the training set
neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet);

// save the trained network into file
neuralNetwork.save("or_perceptron.nnet");

// load the saved network
neuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.createFromFile("or_perceptron.nnet");

// set network input
neuralNetwork.setInput(1, 1);

// calculate network
neuralNetwork.calculate();

// get network output
double[] networkOutput = neuralNetwork.getOutput();
for (double res : networkOutput) {
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

This works, but I want to train something like this:

Input:  `0.3` , `0.5`
Output : `0.2`

It keeps training forever, what is wrong with neuroph, or it doesn't work at all ?

Comment: When you say "It keeps training forever", that is to say that the program seems to block before the print ?

Answer (score 0):

At the end the only thing that worked was to load the training set from external files. Maybe there is another solution, but that was the only thing that worked for me at the end.